# I'm having issues with rendering depth

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer

I'm using GLES2 to make graphics, because I intend to make a mobile application, so it has different things from classic opengl, in the part of creating a framebuffer, I looked for how to do it, and I made a simple one, but I had a depth problem

[image]

I saw some more examples and I saw that I should add a texture for the depth, I tried to add it but it doesn't work, the texture is black, I'll leave the code snippet where I create the framebuffer

```
//texture

glGenTextures(1, &FBO_Texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO_Texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 600, 600, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//depth texture

/*glGenTextures(1, &this->FBO_depth);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO_depth);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 600, 600, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);*/

//frame buffer

glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO_Texture, 0);
//glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO_depth, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *internalFormat*, *format* and *type* arguments of [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) have to match and have follow special rules. If the *format* is `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, then the *type* cannot be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Try `GL_FLOAT` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`:

<s>`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 600, 600, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);`</s>

```cpp
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 600, 600, 0,
             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

Comment: I tested it and it worked, it makes sense as it will store a depth number, thanks for the answer